# Ordering of m-matrix inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse

Assume $A$ and $B$ are two non-singular m-matrices. Are there any theorems that would help me make conclusions about element-wise ordering of $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$? For example, if I know $A \geq B$, where "$\geq$" indicates $a_{ij} \geq 
 b_{ij}$, can I make any conclusions about the element-wise ordering of $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$?